# How to add spinner validation in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, validation, spinner

I Have added a spinner widget to my main class activity, I want to validate that the user has selected a value in a similar way as i did for three other EditText widgets. Can someone help me? I populated the spinner through entries and an array string. The code used so far is attached below for both the main class activity and the strings xml file which contains the array.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button event_post_button;
EditText event_date_txt_edit,event_time_txt_edit,event_participant_txt_edit;
Spinner discipline_name_spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    event_date_txt_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.event_date_txt_edit);
    event_time_txt_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.event_time_txt_edit);
    event_participant_txt_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.event_participant_txt_edit);
    event_post_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.event_post_button);
    discipline_name_spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.discipline_name_spinner);
    event_post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(event_date_txt_edit.length()==0){
                event_date_txt_edit.setError("Required Field");
            }
            else if (event_time_txt_edit.length()==0){
                        event_time_txt_edit.setError("Required Field");
            }
            else if (event_participant_txt_edit.length()==0){
                        event_participant_txt_edit.setError("Required Field");
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"All required fields were inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```js
    <string-array name="sport_names">
        <item>Football</item>
        <item>Basketball</item>
        <item>Baseball</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String selected_item = discipline_name_spinner.getSelectedItem();

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selected_item)){
// no item selected
}
```

Add this code inside event_post_button.setOnClickListener()